# how to convert time with zone to timestamp in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timestamp

I have a datetime string as "2013-01-11 06:30:00 UTC", I want to convert it to unix timestamp 1357887192, in terms of seconds.

What is the most convenient way?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just add .to_i like so:

```
Time.zone.parse("2013-01-11 06:30:00 UTC").to_i
```